.NET MAUI how to render HTML in Label
.NET MAUI To render HTML content in a Label on iOS and Android, I am using the TextType="Html" attribute on the Label element. However, iOS does not render any HTML, while Android only supports bold text. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?"
                  <Label Text="{Binding texto}"
                                         Style="{StaticResource CommonTextStyle}"
                                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                         x:Name="LabelText"
                                         FontSize="17"
                                         TextType="Html"
                                         HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                         VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                                         Margin="15,0"/>

I want the TextType="Html" to recognize the HTML tags in my text and display them on the screen.

what HTML are you trying to render?  As noted in the docs, Displaying HTML in a Label is limited to the HTML tags that are supported by the underlying platform.


However, iOS does not render any HTML, while Android only supports bold text. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?"

You can use handler(platform native code) to achieve it.
For more info you can see my solution of this case: Unable to set LineHeight on Label with TextType set to 'HTML' (Maui).
